# Can't enable sceen sharing on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, sharing

I can't enable screen sharing despite there is an option for it. The button can't be toggled ON. I'm using ubuntu 19.04. Vino is already installed.

How can I enable screen sharing?

[image: enable]

Comment: What is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: @Kulfy The output is `x11`. What does it mean?

Comment: My computer is connected to UGM-Hotspot. When I connected to another wireless connection at home, for example, I can enable screen sharing. Though I know there are other computers that can enable screen sharing via UGM-Hotspot.